# Is there any word that starts with "A", ends with "Z" and contains "T" in English?

Tags: word, scrabble

While playing Scrabble, I needed to find a word that starts with A and ends with Z and contains T.

Is there such a word or should I keep thinking for a few more days?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, please take the [tour] when you're able, and check out the [help]. It looks like you're playing scrabble, so knowing your board state and available words would be helpful!

Comment: [Here](https://onelook.com/?w=a*t*z&ssbp=1) you go.

Comment: This exact question was also posted (and closed) a few hours earlier on [SE EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610940/is-there-any-word-that-starts-with-a-ends-with-z-and-contains-t-in-englis). Are you a sock puppet?

Comment: @WeatherVane Seems possible, both accounts have been members of those sites for 2 days.

Comment: +1 love it. Nice misdirection.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe not the intended answer, but the ALPHABET starts with A, ends with Z and has a T in it.

Comment: Haha, very nice :) I like to think the OP is making a joke and you've rumbled it...

Answer (score 1):

There's no word in SOWPODS or TWL matching that pattern.

I used [Quinapalus](https://www.quinapalus.com) (I'm unaffiliated to the site) to search [SOWPODS](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/match?pat=a*t*z&misp=0&minl=1&maxl=31&sps=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&sbs=&outp=0&dict=4&ent=Search) and [TWL](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/match?pat=a*t*z&misp=0&minl=1&maxl=31&sps=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&sbs=&outp=0&dict=5&ent=Search).

Those two are listed as being used in Scrabble, on [Quinapalus's Dictionary page](https://www.quinapalus.com/dicts.html):

> - SOWPODS, about 270000 words, is a standard word list used for Scrabble and other word games all over the world
> - TWL, about 180000 words, is a standard word list used for Scrabble and other word games in the United States and elsewhere

There are [word matches across the other dictionaries](https://www.quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/match?pat=a*t*z&misp=0&minl=1&maxl=31&sps=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&sbs=&outp=0&dict=6&ent=Search), but I will leave the question of which dictionaries match with which words to the reader to determine.

At the time of writing, none of the Quinapalus results are valid Scrabble words. You can check that on the [official Scrabble dictionary page](https://shop.hasbro.com/en-us/scrabble/dictionary#dictionary).